# Primefaces file upload not working

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

Trying to get jsf fileUploadListener to work just does not seem to do anything trying to just get a printline when hitting {fileUploadView.handleFileUpload} nothing seems to be happening.
UI loads up fine on localhost:8080/index.jsf after clicking on choose file I select a file then after pressing upload button nothing happens no errors in logs or print lines printing everything from display point of view seems to be fine.

index.xhtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
          xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/project/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-glass-x" />

        <f:view>
            <h:head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />

                <title>test</title>
            </h:head>


            <h:body>
                <h:form>
                    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true"
                                  update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />

                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
                </h:form>
            </h:body>
        </f:view>
    </html>
```

FileUploadView.java (bean)

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FileUploadView {

    private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        System.out.println("handel file upoad =-=-=-=-=-");
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }

    public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
        System.out.println("uploading file get =-=-=-=");
        return uploadedFile;
    }

    public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
                System.out.println("uploading file set =-=-=-=");

        this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

add enctype in your form.

```
    enctype="multipart/form-data" in your <h:form>
```

```
    replace you  <h:form> with  <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: please edit your answer (formatting wise)

Answer (score 0):

their are two problems i see in your code
the first one is you should use

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    your code here
</h:form>
```

and add ajax=false attribute to commandButton

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />


        <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadView.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"/>

        <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{fileUploadView.upload}" disabled="true" />
    </h:form>
```

official doc https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml

Unrelated Ijust notice something funny, the upload doesn't work on primefaces official showcase xP